# Unity 3D only show wallpaper and Icon if set, where did it go?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, session, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Unity is gone. As I have use user defined session on 12.04, I'm back to default sesion (ubuntu) and then unity is gone, how to reveal it.

How to get to Compiz without that unity taskbar? Even Ubuntu 3D on top missing. On Ubuntu 2d it appears fine. help me to reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following some of these instructions:

http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/04/missing-top-and-side-panels-in-unity.html

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Answer (score 0):

right click at that `desktop` of unity and create `a folder` and open it . then move to `filesystem > usr > bin > applications` . there you can find compiz settings manager . open it and enable the unity plugin and restart .

else try as 
`ctrl`+ `Alt`+`F1` then login there and type as 
`unity --reset` then `restart` your pc.

Comment: are you sure, that he installed `compizconfig-settings-manager`. It wasn't installed by default

Comment: but he mentioned asa  wanna get to compiz , means installled

Comment: `compiz` is installed by default, but not `compizconfig-settings-manager`. You can check that by running a Live CD

Answer (score 0):

as well just go to unity 2D and go to Compiz, setting, & then plugin list. you lost that because you/I: remove: -unityshell, & -unitymtgrabhandles. so put that back but lost all the setting include the transparency. so............. I need MyUnity on software center to fix that configuration (WHAT?! tired...!)

Comment: so we may not sad to this. we can rebuild it again, except the school. so..., we need approx 2 month to remind it again except for who is high IQ just need 12 hours when holiday but with resisted of school such homework, we need 2 year (actualy when final test).

Answer (score 0):

If you actually get chance to log into the desktop *(though not working unity)*, Opening a terminal and doing `unity --reset` will do the job.

#### Procedure:

- Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Type `unity --reset` to reset the Unity settings.
- Then type `unity` to start unity.
- Then **without closing the terminal**, Logout from session and then Login again.